# How to count the total amount of rows in a mysql database using VB

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to count the number of rows that my mysql table has  whith VB using something like " Select  count (fieldID) from tableID where fieldID='querysearchstate'" and show the result in a label.

Can anyone of you please help me?

Comment: Note that i've edited my answer to demonstrate how you use parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e80y5yhx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). So create a `MySqlConnection` and a  `MySqlCommand` and use `ExecuteScalar` to retrieve the single value:

```
Using con As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("Connection-String")
    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.TableName where FieldID=@FieldID", con)
        con.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@FieldID", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = querysearchstate
        Dim count As Int32 = CType(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Int32)
        LabelResult.Text = String.Format("Count of records: {0}", count)
    End Using
End Using
```

I've used sql-parameters to prevent sql-injection and to ensure that the correct type/size will be used.

I've used [`Using`-statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) to ensure that all unmanaged resources will be disposed even on error. This will also close the connection implicitly. It is best practice to use it always when the class implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I've tried to use your code,  but ,for some reason, it's   still not working...   :/

Comment: @user3360347: what is not working, have you used the debugger to check what's going on? Do you get an exception?

Comment: @user3360347: the debugger never _returns_ an exception. You have to set a breakpoint, inspect the values and hit F10 to go to the next line. Then you can see what's going on or if there is an exception. You can even execute a line in the quick-watch window to check if this line will trigger an exception without stopping the program. If it's "doing nothing" this code is not executed at all. But then i can't help you since i don't know your code.